# ExtJS 4.0.2a render and afterrender

Tags: extjs, render

I have a `TreeGrid`. In column renderer, I call some function1.

In tree listeners afterrender, I call some function2.

When I refresh the page, it calls function1 then function2. But when I am sorting columns, function1 gets called but function2 does not.

```
var tree = Ext.create("Ext.tree.Panel", {
    columns: [{
        text: 'text',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'id',
        renderer: function(){
            alert("!!!");
        },
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
        alert("!");
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want function2 to be called on column sorting? Then you should use another event to listen for.

Comment: Not only on column sorting. after all renderer (after all calling function1)

Comment: It might be nice to clarify explicitly that `TreeGrid`s have been superseded by `TreePanel`s as in [this example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/tree/locking-treegrid.html) (see [code with relevent comment here](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/tree/locking-treegrid.js))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`afterrender` is an event on the tree.Panel itself, so it will only be called after the tree.Panel is rendered.

Sounds like the `column renderer` is being called every time the column is rendered; for example, on column sorting.